# Verifying Yang Baxter Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, quantum-groups

$V$ be a 3 dimensional space with basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $q\in \mathbb{C}^\ast$.

$\beta: V\otimes V \to V\otimes V$ defined by
\begin{equation}
\beta(e_i\otimes e_j) = 
    \begin{cases}
        e_i\otimes e_i & \text{if } i = j\\
        q(e_j\otimes e_i) & \text{if } i< j\\
q(e_j\otimes e_i) + (1-q^2)(e_i\otimes e_j)& \text{if } i> j
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}

Is there a **smart way** of verifying that this operator $\beta$ satisfies Yang Baxter Equation?

Let $\beta_1=id\otimes \beta :V\otimes V\otimes V\to V\otimes V\otimes V$ and $\beta_2=\beta\otimes id:V\otimes V\otimes V\to V\otimes V\otimes V$

I need to verify $\beta_1\circ\beta_2\circ\beta_1 = \beta_2\circ\beta_1\circ\beta_2$.

checking on every elements or computing matrices and then performing matrix multiplication are really very painful. Is there any logical reasoning why this operator is a solution to Yang Baxter equation. I found that this operator is called **Jimbo's operator of type $A^{(1)}_2$**. I am not able to figure what that is?

Any motivational comments will also be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into [$R$-matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R-matrix). There are a structure designed to automatically solve Yang Baxter. So maybe the "smart way" you are looking for is simply checking whether or not this can be written into an $R$-matrix.

But of course, I might have not fully understood the subtleties of your question. I am myself pretty new to Quantum Groups...

Comment: Okay, I just checked the Wikipedia page I linked... It's pretty empty. My source of knowledge of these is "Quantum Groups" by Kassel. (I think it's chapter 2) Sorry for not have better sources available.